# How to click top menu with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, dropdown

I'm trying to click on the "Consultas" from the top menu of this site: https://siconfi.tesouro.gov.br/siconfi/index.jsf

this would be the path on the site:

```
                    <ul id="menuSuperior" class="nav ">
                        <li class="dropdown">                           
                            <a id="drop2" href="#" role="button" style="padding: 5px 7px;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Página de apresentação"> Apresentação <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
            <li><a id="linkMenu38" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=38" title="Link para Histórico">Histórico</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu82" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=82" title="Link para Glossário">Glossário</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu21" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=21" title="Link para Apresentação">Apresentação</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu23" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=23" title="Link para Legislação">Legislação</a></li>                      
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop3" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Publicações importantes "> 
                                Publicações <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
            <li><a id="linkMenu30104" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=30104" title="Link para Dicas da Jacque">Dicas da Jacque</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu21904" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=21904" title="Link para Cartilha do Finbra">Cartilha do Finbra</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu29" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=29" title="Link para Plano de Contas">Plano de Contas</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu13703" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=13703" title="Link para Manual de Procedimentos">Manual de Procedimentos</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu42" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=42" title="Link para Instruções e Guias de Preenchimento">Instruções e Guias de Preenchimento</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu37" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=37" title="Link para Balanço do Setor Público Nacional">Balanço do Setor Público Nacional</a></li>                        
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop4" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Informações sobre a Taxonomia"> Taxonomia <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
            <li><a id="linkMenu581" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=581" title="Link para Documentação">Documentação</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu601" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=601" title="Link para Fundamentos de XBRL">Fundamentos de XBRL</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu584" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=584" title="Link para Taxonomia Siconfi">Taxonomia Siconfi</a></li>                      
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop5" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Informações sobre MSC"> Matriz de Saldos Contábeis <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
            <li><a id="linkMenu12503" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=12503" title="Link para Documentação">Documentação</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu13503" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=13503" title="Link para Dicas rápidas">Dicas rápidas</a></li>
            <li><a id="linkMenu12302" rel="tooltip" href="/siconfi/pages/public/conteudo/conteudo.jsf?id=12302" title="Link para Sobre a Matriz de Saldos Contábeis">Sobre a Matriz de Saldos Contábeis</a></li>                        
    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a id="drop5" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" rel="tooltip-top" title="Consultas"> Consultas <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-horizontal-ul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
                                 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                  <a href="#">Consultar Finbra</a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                   <li><a id="formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRA" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget has-tooltip" aria-label="Contas Anuais" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('formMenuSuperior',{'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRA':'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRA'}).submit('formMenuSuperior');return false;" title="Contas Anuais">Contas Anuais</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a id="formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARGF" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget has-tooltip" aria-label="RGF" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('formMenuSuperior',{'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARGF':'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARGF'}).submit('formMenuSuperior');return false;" title="RGF">RGF</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a id="formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARREO" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget has-tooltip" aria-label="RREO" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('formMenuSuperior',{'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARREO':'formMenuSuperior:linkMenuConsultarFINBRARREO'}).submit('formMenuSuperior');return false;" title="RREO">RREO</a>
                                    </li>                           
                                  </ul>
                                </li>
```

My goal is to get to the "RGF", however, for that, I need to click on "Consultations" to open a submenu and then click on "Consultar Fiber" and finally "RGF", but so far still not able to click on "Consultations"
This is my code for it:

```
driver.get (https://siconfi.tesouro.gov.br/siconfi/index.jsf) 
time.sleep (20)
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*/a[@id='drop5' and text()=' Consultas ']").click()
```

when i run i get the error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*/a[@id='drop5' and text()=' Consultas ']"}
```

I also tried but it didn't work

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
dropdown = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='drop5' and text()=' Consultas ']"))).click()
```

am i wrong in xpath?

Comment: Hello, for some reason the clicks were not happening using selenium in google colab. I solved my problem using vscode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - if an element has an ID, there is no need to look for it by text or other attributes. There can be only one item with this ID, never 2 or more, just one.

Second, in UI tests you must always wait. The page (the site) takes time to load. So use sleep of 5-10 seconds before you click, or use webDriverWait and wait for the element to be clickable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used the id and the text because there is another tag "a" with the same id, I also used a sleep time but I still got an error

Comment: I was able to find "your" element on my browser. Give a higher wait value, or try to click on the father element of son element of this element. You can also try to inject JavaScript code to the element and by doing so - "hard clicking" on the element

Comment: I tried with a longer wait and with full xpath but it didn't work, I'll try to click on any other element on the site, I took a look that it could be a frame or iframe but I believe it's not my case